# Storing the scraped data to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I wrote a scrapy bot to scrape the data and now I wanted to store it into the MySQL. I wrote a pipeline script to do so. But its not working don't know what issue its facing. Can anyone suggest what exactly is the issue. The code run perfectly I think it is not able to connect to the mySQL only.

The Scrapy bot code is

```
from..items import NdtvItem

class NdtvReviewSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ndtv_review'
    page_number = 2
    start_urls = ['https://www.ndtv.com/movie-reviews/page-1'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        items = {}

        i = 1
        count = response.xpath('//*[@id="ins_storylist"]/ul/li[{}]/div[2]/div[1]/a/i/text()'.format("*")).getall()
        count = len(count)
        while i<=count:
            outputs = NdtvItem()
            outputs['page_title'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="ins_storylist"]/ul/li[{}]/div[2]/div[1]/a/i/text()'.format(i)).get()
            outputs['review_content'] = response.xpath("//*[@id='ins_storylist']/ul/li[{}]/div[2]/div[3]/text()".format(i)).get()
            outputs['review_link'] = response.xpath("//*[@id='ins_storylist']/ul/li[{}]/div[2]/div[1]/a/@href".format(i)).get()
            i+=1
            fl = 0
            if outputs['page_title'] == []:
                outputs['page_title'] = ''
                fl+=1
            if outputs['review_content'] == []:
                outputs['review_content'] = ''
                fl+=1
            if outputs['review_link'] == []:
                outputs['review_link'] = ''
                fl += 1
            else:
                yield outputs
                #if outputs['review_content'] != []:
                 #   if 'Review:' in outputs['review_content'].split(" ") or 'review:' in outputs['review_content'].split(" ") :
                  #      yield outputs


        next_page = 'https://www.ndtv.com/movie-reviews/page-' + str(NdtvReviewSpider.page_number) +''
        if NdtvReviewSpider.page_number <= 15:
            NdtvReviewSpider.page_number += 1  
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
        
        pass
```

The pipeline script is

```
# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

import mysql.connector

class ReviewBotPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            passwd = 'xxxxxx',
            database = 'review'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute(""" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS review_tb """)
        self.curr.execute(""" create table review_tb(
            page_title text,
            review_content text,
            review_link text
            ) """)
    def process_item(self, outputs, spider):
        self.store_db(outputs)
        return outputs

    def store_db(self, outputs):
        self.curr.execute(""" insert into review_tb values(%s,%s,%s)""",(
            outputs['page_title'][0],
            outputs['review_content'][0],
            outputs['review_link'][0]
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

And this the error what I'm getting.

```
  File "/Users/divyanshu/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/divyanshu/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 154, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "/Users/divyanshu/review_bot/review_bot/pipelines.py", line 33, in process_item
    self.store_db(outputs)
  File "/Users/divyanshu/review_bot/review_bot/pipelines.py", line 40, in store_db
    outputs['review_link']
  File "/Users/divyanshu/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 248, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "/Users/divyanshu/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 626, in prepare_for_mysql
    result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(*params)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type list cannot be converted
```

Comment: Hi! On StackOverflow you better ask precise questions. You should do some more debugging to find out the exact issue, then you can ask how to solve that exact issue!

Comment: You need to include precise information on the error that you are facing, don't expect us to run it and discover the problem. Run it and update the error stack trace to the question

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 i tried debugging and this is the error what I'm getting.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I provided that what error I'm getting

Comment: Is this the full Traceback? It seems to start halway through

Comment: error shows problem with `outputs['review_link']` in `store_db()` and it says `Python type list cannot be converted` - it can meas you have list in this variable and it doesn't know what to do with this. You could use `print(outputs['review_link'])`  and `print(type( outputs['review_link'] ))` to check what you have in this variable. Or maybe you forgot  `[0]` in your real code.

Comment: @furas i removed the [0] from the piplines also still this continue.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper its full trackback.

Comment: @furas its a string

Comment: if `outputs['review_link']` is a list and you remove `[0]` then you will have list as argument and then it can make problem. If `outputs['review_link']` is a string then using `[0]` you get only first char - but this should still work. We can't run it to test code so we can only suggest to use `print()` with all variables which you use to see if there is list.

Comment: BTW: problem has `prepare_for_mysql` in `connection_cext.py` so you can edit it and add `print()` in this function to see what values (`params`) makes problem.

Comment: @furas I got it connected but its getting only first letter as you said in db. How should I modify that?

Comment: simply see `print( outputs['review_link'] )` and `print( outputs['review_link'][0] )` to see difference. You have to use without `[0]` to get full string.

Comment: BTW: because you use `.get()` so you can't get list of elements and checking `outputs['page_title'] == []` is useless.  You could get list only with `.getall()`

Answer (score 0):

Another method. The code for extracting and storing data is simpler and more readable.

```
from simplified_scrapy import Spider, SimplifiedDoc, SimplifiedMain, utils
from simplified_scrapy.core.mysql_objstore import MysqlObjStore
from simplified_html.request_render import RequestRender

class ReviewBotPipeline(MysqlObjStore):
    def saveObj(self, data):
        conn = None
        cur = None
        try:
            conn = self.connect()
            cur = conn.cursor()
            try:
                cur.execute("insert into review_tb(page_title,review_content,review_link) values(%s,%s,%s)",
                            (data['page_title'], data['review_content'],
                             data['review_link']))
                return conn.commit()
            except Exception as err:
                conn.rollback()
                print(err)
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
        finally:
            if (cur): cur.close()
            if (conn): conn.close()

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'ndtv_review'
    start_urls = [{
        'url': 'https://www.ndtv.com/movie-reviews/page-1',
        'requestMethod': 'render' # The download mode is 'render'
    }]  # Entry page
    concurrencyPer1s = 1
    refresh_urls = True
    obj_store = ReviewBotPipeline(
        name, {
            'host': '127.0.0.1',
            'port': 3306,
            'user': 'root',
            'pwd': 'root',
            'dbName': 'review',
            'tbName': 'review_tb'
        })

    # Download page using headless browser. start
    # pyppeteer needs to be installed
    req = RequestRender({
        'executablePath':
        '/Applications/chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
    })

    def renderUrl(self, url, callback):
        self.req.get(url['url'], self._callback, extr_data=(url, callback))

    def _callback(self, html, url, extr_data):
        extr_data[1](html, extr_data[0], self)
    # Download page using headless browser. end

    def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
        doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
        datas = []
        lis = doc.selects('div#ins_storylist>li')
        for li in lis:
            outputs = {}
            a = li.select('div.nstory_header>a')
            if not a: continue
            outputs['page_title'] = a.text
            outputs['review_content'] = li.select('div.nstory_intro').text
            outputs['review_link'] = a.href
            datas.append(outputs)
        lstA = doc.selects('div.new_pagination>a')
        return {"Urls": lstA, "Data": datas}


SimplifiedMain.startThread(MySpider())  # Start download
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/spider_examples